# Is a 2D integer coordinate in a set?

Tags: c++, set, comparator

I have a list of 2D integer coordinates (coordinate pairs). I'd like to read these in and, later, determine if a point has been read.

The integer data may fall anywhere within the range offered by the integer data type, but the number of actual data points will be small. Therefore, using a 2D array to track which points have been read is impractical. A `set` seems like a good way of doing this.

My current code to accomplish this is as follows:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class grid_cell{
  public:
    int x,y;
    grid_cell(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    grid_cell(){}
    bool operator< (const grid_cell& a) const { return y<a.y || x<a.x; }
};

int main(){
    set<grid_cell> bob;

    bob.insert(grid_cell(1,1));
    bob.insert(grid_cell(-1,1));
    bob.insert(grid_cell(1,-1));
    bob.insert(grid_cell(-1,-1));
    cout<<bob.count(grid_cell(1,1))<<endl;
    cout<<bob.count(grid_cell(-1,1))<<endl;
    cout<<bob.count(grid_cell(1,-1))<<endl;
    cout<<bob.count(grid_cell(-1,-1))<<endl;
}
```

But know something is wrong because I have inserted cells which the set later tells me it doesn't know about. The output of the above should be all true, but, instead, is as follows.

```
1
1
0 <-?????
1
```

I suspect the comparator is a problem, but am not sure how to fix it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your comparison operator makes no sense. Before you do C++, sit down with a pen and paper and work out what your relation describes.

Comment: Try coordinate `(0,1)` and coordinate `(1,0)` with your code.  In either order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comparison is indeed wrong. It does not satisfy the required semantics. Try something like this:

```
bool operator< (const grid_cell& a) const { return x<a.x || (x==a.x && y<a.y); }
```

Here is a good article on the subject:

http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/a-strategy-for-defining-order-relations/240147625